# I need to send an encrypted pdf file via email in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, npm

I am generating the PDF using html-pdf node library and then encrypting it using node-qpdf library.

```
pdf.create(htmlString, {format: 'A4', timeout: 600000})
            .toFile(filePath, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    logger.error('Error while creating the pdf file ::->', err.stack);
                    return reject(err);
                } else {
                    logger.info('Successfully able to create the file in tmp');
                    encrypt(filePath, '/tmp/' + _.get(lead, 'code', '00003') + '_receipt_encrypted.pdf');
                    return resolve(data);
                }
            });
var encrypt = function (inputFile, outputFile) {
    let exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var ownerPass = 'ownerpasswd'
    var userPass = 'ownerpasswd'
    let cmd = 'qpdf --encrypt ' + ownerPass + ' ' + userPass + ' 256 -- ' + inputFile + ' ' + outputFile

    exec(cmd, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("The error", err, err.stack)
        } else {
            console.log("The PDF is encrypted")
        }
    })
}
```

I am able to generate the enccrypted pdf file in the /tmp/ folder bit when I am trying to send it via Email, I am getting the error
 `[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/A6rz2K-p2n_receipt_encrypted.pdf'] {`

Here is the code for reading file and sending it via email.

````
                if (err) {
                    console.log('error in reading encrypted file================= ', err, err.stack);
                }
                var attachment = {
                    content: data.toString('base64'),
                    name: encryptedFileName,
                    type: "application/pdf"
                };
                sendReceiptEmail(lead,attachment);
                logger.log("end of receipt pdf creation");
            })
            return Promise.resolve();
        })```
````

Comment: Looks like code is trying to read the encrypted PDF file from the `/tmp/` folder before it is fully written to disk by the `qpdf` command. I would refactor to use fs promises. Then use something like `await fs.access(tmp_file_path)` to wait until it is on disk.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're having an issue with async code execution. The call to `encrypt` looks good, since that function is called inside the `pdf..toFile` callback function. Maybe you need to make sure `sendReceiptEmail` is called after `encrypt` is done, inside the `exec` callback function.

As Raya commented, I'd suggest to refactor the code to use promises or async code execution as well.

Comment: Cool Thanks it worked, seems like the issue was in asynnc code execution.